# HTML Button Select specific column on table

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how to select a specific column on the table..

This function make select all table...
I Just want to select Heading 2,3 and parent Only...
Like this pic :
[image]

I want to select text for Copying a columns (Ctrl+C)...

I'm trying this and working for select all content on the table...

```js
function selectElementContents(el) {
  var body = document.body,
    range, sel;
  if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
    range = document.createRange();
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    try {
      range.selectNodeContents(el);
      sel.addRange(range);
    } catch (e) {
      range.selectNode(el);
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  } else if (body.createTextRange) {
    range = body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(el);
    range.select();
  }
}
```

```css
#thead {
  background-color: #fffd99;
}

#table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="select table" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('table') );">

<br>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
      <th>Heading 3</th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1774</td>
          <td>Content 1</td>
          <td>Content 2</td>
          <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1774</td>
          <td>Content 1</td>
          <td>Content 2</td>
          <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1774</td>
          <td>Content 1</td>
          <td>Content 2</td>
          <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is a reason you were not allowed to post the link to fiddle. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55216039/edit), then the `[<>]` snippet editor and post the code HERE instead - like I did for you

Comment: Im sorry, i dont know about that.. Thanks before...  :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table th').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
    $(this).removeClass("selected"); 
    columnIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('table tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').removeClass("selected");
}else{
    $(this).addClass("selected"); 
    columnIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('table tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').addClass("selected");
     $('table tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').each(function(){
     console.log('Selected value:',$(this).html());
     });
}

});
```

```css
.selected{
color:#0000FF;
background-color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="4" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th>HEAD 1</th>
        <th>HEAD 2</th>
        <th>HEAD 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DATA 1</td>
        <td>DATA 2</td>
        <td>DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>DATA 1</td>
        <td>DATA 2</td>
        <td>DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>DATA 1</td>
        <td>DATA 2</td>
        <td>DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>DATA 1</td>
        <td>DATA 2</td>
        <td>DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>DATA 1</td>
        <td>DATA 2</td>
        <td>DATA 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope This will help you. Click Head and select Entire column.

Comment: Thanks for Answer... But its not selected... I want to select text for Copy (Ctrl+C)..